# SQLite check for duplicate username

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I would like to know how do I properly traverse through an entire username column and compare edit text string to all of them and only return true if there is a match. I have a sign up system already done but it is not checking for duplicate usernames which it should be doing. So I wrote a method but it seem to be crashing my app Here is the crash message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
```

I am using SQLite as my database obviously as the title suggests. Here is the database code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "usersDB";
    public static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_SAT_READING = "sat_reading";
    public static final String KEY_SAT_MATH = "sat_math";
    public static final String KEY_ACT_ENGLISH = "act_english";
    public static final String KEY_ACT_MATH = "act_math";
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS
                + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_SAT_READING + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_SAT_MATH + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_ACT_ENGLISH + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_ACT_MATH + " TEXT "
                + ")"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public User authenticate(String username, String password) {
        User currentUser = null;
         Cursor cursor = db.query(
                TABLE_USERS,
                null,
                KEY_USERNAME + "=? AND " + KEY_PASSWORD + "=?",
                new String[]{username, password},
                null, null, null
        );
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            currentUser = new User();
            currentUser.setUserId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
            currentUser.setUsername(username);
            currentUser.setPassword("");
            currentUser.setSatReading(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SAT_READING)));
            currentUser.setSatMath(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SAT_MATH)));
            currentUser.setActReading(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ACT_ENGLISH)));
            currentUser.setActMath(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ACT_MATH)));
        }
        cursor.close();
        return currentUser;
    }

    public Cursor getScores(String username, SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "SELECT sat_reading, sat_math, act_english, act_math FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE " + KEY_USERNAME + "=?";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{String.valueOf(username)});
        return cursor;
    }

    public boolean checkDupUsername(String username, SQLiteDatabase db) { //The method I wrote to check for duplicates
        String query = "SELECT username FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE " + KEY_USERNAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{String.valueOf(username)});
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            if(username.matches(cursor.getString(0))) {
                return true;
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }

    public class User {
        public long userId;
        public String username;
        public String password;
        public String satReading;
        public String satMath;
        public String actReading;
        public String actMath;

        public User() {
        }

        public User(String name, String password) {
            this(-1L, name, password, null, null, null, null);
        }

        public User(long id, String name, String password, String satReading, String satMath, String actReading, String actMath) {
            this.userId = id;
            this.username = name;
            this.password = password;
            this.satReading = satReading;
            this.satMath = satMath;
            this.actReading = actReading;
            this.actMath = actMath;
        }

        public long getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(long userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getSatReading() {
            return satReading;
        }

        public void setSatReading(String satReading) {
            this.satReading = satReading;
        }

        public String getSatMath() {
            return satMath;
        }

        public void setSatMath(String satMath) {
            this.satMath = satMath;
        }

        public String getActReading() {
            return actReading;
        }

        public void setActReading(String actReading) {
            this.actReading = actReading;
        }

        public String getActMath() {
            return actMath;
        }

        public void setActMath(String actMath) {
            this.actMath = actMath;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the sign up activity itself with a method `newUser()` which creates a new user and has a series of checks

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private LinearLayout rellay1;
    private RelativeLayout rellay2;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            rellay1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rellay2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        rellay1 = findViewById(R.id.sign_up);
        rellay2 = findViewById(R.id.signup_bottom_nav);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 150);

        Button createUser = findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        createUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                newUser();
            }
        });

        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        Button clearAll = findViewById(R.id.btn_clear);
        clearAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clearDatabase();
            }
        });
    }

    public void clearDatabase() {
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete(dbHelper.TABLE_USERS, null, null);
        System.out.println("Database successfully cleared");
    }

    public void newUser() {
        EditText usernameInput = findViewById(R.id.signup_username);
        EditText passwordInput = findViewById(R.id.signup_password);
        EditText confirmPasswordInput = findViewById(R.id.signup_confirtm_password);
        EditText satScoreReadingInput = findViewById(R.id.signup_sat_reading);
        EditText satScoreMathInput = findViewById(R.id.signup_sat_math);
        EditText actScoreReadingInput = findViewById(R.id.signup_act_reading);
        EditText actScoreMathInput = findViewById(R.id.signup_act_math);

        String usersUsername = usernameInput.getText().toString();
        String usersPassword = passwordInput.getText().toString();
        String usersConfirmPassword = confirmPasswordInput.getText().toString();
        String usersSatReadingScore = satScoreReadingInput.getText().toString();
        String usersSatMathScore = satScoreMathInput.getText().toString();
        String usersActReadingScore = actScoreReadingInput.getText().toString();
        String usersActMathScore = actScoreMathInput.getText().toString();
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        if(usersUsername.matches("") || usersPassword.matches("") || usersConfirmPassword.matches("") || usersSatReadingScore.matches("") || usersSatMathScore.matches("") || usersActReadingScore.matches("") || usersActMathScore.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "all fields are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(dbHelper.checkDupUsername(usersUsername, database)) { //this line crashes the app
            Toast.makeText(this, "this username is unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            int satReadingScoreValue = Integer.parseInt(usersSatReadingScore);
            int satMathScoreValue = Integer.parseInt(usersSatMathScore);
            double actReadingScoreValue = Double.parseDouble(usersActReadingScore);
            double actMathScoreValue = Double.parseDouble(usersActMathScore);
            if(usersPassword.equals(usersConfirmPassword) && actReadingScoreValue < 36.1 && actMathScoreValue < 36.1 && satReadingScoreValue < 801 && satMathScoreValue < 801) {

                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(dbHelper.KEY_USERNAME, usersUsername);
                contentValues.put(dbHelper.KEY_PASSWORD, usersPassword);
                contentValues.put(dbHelper.KEY_SAT_READING, usersSatReadingScore);
                contentValues.put(dbHelper.KEY_SAT_MATH, usersSatMathScore);
                contentValues.put(dbHelper.KEY_ACT_ENGLISH, usersActReadingScore);
                contentValues.put(dbHelper.KEY_ACT_MATH, usersActMathScore);

                database.insert(dbHelper.TABLE_USERS, null, contentValues);
                dbHelper.close();

                Toast.makeText(this, "User " + usersUsername + " created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                usernameInput.getText().clear();
                passwordInput.getText().clear();
                confirmPasswordInput.getText().clear();
                satScoreReadingInput.getText().clear();
                satScoreMathInput.getText().clear();
                actScoreReadingInput.getText().clear();
                actScoreMathInput.getText().clear();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "make sure password matches and test scores are within range", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `selection` is not an expression and does not have any `?` but you have one element in `selectionArgs`.

Your query in the`checkDupUsername` should be like following

```
String query = "SELECT username FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE " + KEY_USERNAME + "=?";
```

Comment: omg I am sorry, I have been working on my project all day and totally missed it. Thats my bad, thank you, this is so obvious now that I am embarrassed. Time to go to sleep

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :-

```
String query = "SELECT username FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE " + KEY_USERNAME;
```

Which does not have a parameter to be bound (so there are 0 to be bound)

You should have :-

```
String query = "SELECT username FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE " + KEY_USERNAME + "=?;
```

The 1 argument as per `new String[]{String.valueOf(username)}` in the line `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{String.valueOf(username)}` can now be bound to replace the `?`.